# Mocking and patching keystoneclient in Python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, magicmock

I am writing unittest for a class looks like below. I am trying to assert if logging is properly called with patch keystoneclient. The class looks like below. Problem is, I cannot pass through the for statement and can never get to LOGGER.warning or LOGGER.info even after patching CredentialManager. I am new to whole unittest and Mock so I might not be understanding something clearly.

```
from keystoneclient.v3.client import Client
from keystoneclient.v3.credentials import CredentialManager
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
    ...

    def myfunc(self):

        new_credentials = {}
        client = Client(
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            auth_url=self.auth_url,
            user_domain_name=self.user_domain_name,
            domain_name=self.domain_name
        )

        abc = CredentialManager(client)

        for credential in abc.list():

            defg = str(credential.type)
            (access, secret) = _anotherfunc(credential.blob)

            if not defg:
                LOGGER.warning('no abc')

            if defg in new_credentials:
                LOGGER.info('Ignoring duplate')

            new_credentials[defg] = (access, secret)
```

My unit tests looks something like this,

```
import unittest
from mock import patch, MagicMock
import MyClass

LOGGER = logging.getLogger('my_module')

@patch('MyClass.Client', autospec = True)
@patch('MyClass.CredentialManager', autospec = True)
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_logger_warning(self,,mock_client, mock_cm):
        with patch.object(LOGGER, 'warning') as mock_warning:
            obj = MyClass()
            mock_warning.assert_called_with('no abc')
```

The error I am getting looks like this.

```
    for credential in abc.list():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'list'
```

So even after patching CredentialManager with autospect, I am getting error on abc.list(). I need to get to the point where I can test LOGGER but it seems like this patching does not work for list(). How should I make this error go away and be able to pass through the for statment so I can assert on logging?

Comment: Can you fix the code `if`s in `for` cycle have no sense. I can file an answer but I need to understand exactly hot to write the test: in your case `abc` cannot be `False` in loop.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. It should have been defg instead of abc in the if statement. I'm trying to write a unittest to assert if log is being called successfully

Comment: Which python and mock versions you use?

Comment: Python 2.7.5 and mock is 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many details to cover in this answer:

1. Patch order: `@patch` decorator are applied as stack, that means first decorator -> last mock argument
2. If you want that `CredentialManager().list()` return something that contains a empty `type` you should instrument your `mock_cm` to do it
3. You should call `obj.myfunc()` if you want to test something :)

The code:

import unittest
from mock import patch, Mock
import MyClass

```
@patch('MyClass.Client', autospec=True)
@patch('MyClass.CredentialManager', autospec=True)
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    #Use decorator for test case too... is simpler and neat
    @patch("MyClass.LOGGER", autospec=True)
    def test_logger_warning(self, mock_logger, mock_cm, mock_client):
        #pay attention to the mock argument order (first local and the the stack of patches
        # Extract the mock that will represent you abc
        mock_abc = mock_cm.return_value
        # Build a mock for credential with desidered empty type
        mock_credential = Mock(type="")
        # Intrument list() method to return your credential
        mock_abc.list.return_value = [mock_credential]
        obj = MyClass.MyClass()
        # Call the method
        obj.myfunc()
        # Check your logger
        mock_logger.warning.assert_called_with('no abc')
```

Good point to use `autospec=True` for all your patches: it is a good practice.

Anyway I would like encourage you to extract your logging section to a method and test it by some fake credentials: is simpler and a better design: something like

```
def myfunc(self):

    new_credentials = {}
    client = Client(
        username=self.username,
        password=self.password,
        auth_url=self.auth_url,
        user_domain_name=self.user_domain_name,
        domain_name=self.domain_name
    )

    abc = CredentialManager(client)

    for credential in abc.list():
        self.process_credential(credential, new_credentials)

@staticmethod
def process_credential(credential, cache):
    (access, secret) = _anotherfunc(credential.blob)
    defg = str(credential.type)
    MyClass.logging_credential_process(credential, not defg, defg in cache)
    cache[defg] = (access, secret)

@staticmethod
def logging_credential_process(credential, void_type, duplicate):
    if void_type:
        LOGGER.warning('no abc')
    if duplicate:
        LOGGER.info('Ignoring duplate')
```

is simpler to test and looks better.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get it working but have a question. Why can't I use mock_cm.return_value or mock_cm.list()? List() is within CredentialManager class but I am somewhat confused why we have to extract it to mock_abc and use mock_abc.list.return_value.

Comment: @killahjc `mock_cm` is the `CredentialManager` class mock. When your production code use `abc=CredentialManager(client)` `abc` become the `return_value` of `mock_cm`. Later you use `list()` from `abc` and not from `CredentialManager` class. Finally to set `list`'s `return_value` you should set return value of `list`'s mock of `abc` instance (so `mock_cm.return_value`)... One thing more... you forget to upvote/accept the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much once again :)